# Can I run iTunes as a Windows Service?

Tags: itunes, windows, networking, streaming

I'd like to run iTunes as a Windows service on my home dev server which runs Windows 2008 so that I can stream my collection to my AppleTV over my home network. Currently I have to log in to Windows and open iTunes before the AppleTV can see the library. I have tried setting iTunes up as a Windows service so that it'll start at boot time. Not successfully, though, while it appears in the process list it isn't contactable via another instance of iTunes.

Does anyone have any tips on this or am I wasting my time?

Comment: Your question is certainly on-topic here, but I don't know how much help you'll get. Super User might be a better place for the question - if you want it migrated, talk to the moderators about moving it.

Comment: I would sooner set Windows to log in automatically, and then add iTunes to start up automatically.

Comment: I don't want to have to have a user session running - its a server after all ...

Comment: Although this isn't off topic here, it may get more audience with Windows service familiarity over on SuperUser. I'll migrate it presently...

Answer (score 2):

Check out a link [here](http://www.wegotserved.com/2010/10/18/forum-focus-stream-music-video-photos-windows-home-server-apple-tv/) that was originally meant for Windows Home Server, but looks like it could apply nicely to your situation.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's long past, but this post seems to get a high ranking in a Google search.

You can now use the free and open source [iTuneService](https://github.com/clearz/iTuneService/) (formerly JTunes) to wrap iTunes in a windows service.

(Full disclosure - I am a contributor to the project.)

Answer (score 1):

You can basically do this on Windows with [FireDaemon](http://www.firedaemon.com/), This lets you run any program as a service, so this may help you. For specifically iTunes there is a software called [iHomeServer](http://www.bizmodeller.com/iHomeServer_for_iTunes.aspx) (Paid), You may check out that.

These are the best ways to do, but if for any reason they does not work, You may try any of these guides: 
1. [HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/)
2. [MSFN](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/83272-how-to-run-a-program-as-a-service/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give your suggestions a try and report back ...

Comment: Another commercial option with an [iTunes as a service tutorial](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/Apps/RunITunesAsAService.html)

Comment: The #1 suggestion in Akshat Mittal's post worked for me for running itunes as a service on a windows home server (WHS), v1 (first version). I did have to do one thing not mentioned on the #1 link. That was to, when the service was created, use the windows service console to set the service to run as the administrator account - the account that I had installed itunes under on the server.